# Did Evan Longoria save a reporter with bare-hand catch?

Tags: physiology, sport

[Here's what I'm talking about](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/05/13/evan-longoria-catch-video_n_861824.html).

There are a lot of opinions whether it's fake or not, I really don't know!

What are the chances that one (even a professional player, let alone common mortals) can somehow *feel the ball* (did he hear it or what?), make it in 0.5 second to *extend the arm* and *catch with a bare hand* the ball approaching at a huge speed (really, how fast is it?)?

Comment: lol, I misread the name as __Eva__ Longoria (the actress) and thought WTF?

Comment: hahahaha same with me! imagine, i was watching the video expecting to see eva longoria and thinking "WTF, that black chick cant be eva longoria!"

Comment: If the entire event is true, it could be that he saw the ball in the camera lens. Unfortunately, the resolution is too low so we can't see what he's looking at right before he turns. Another interesting point is seventh second of the video. Take a look at it slowed down. After looking at it at 0.06 times normal speed, I'm pretty sure that the ball makes an unnatural turn. They might have had extremely strong wind, but I still doubt that it could have made such an impact on the trajectory.

Comment: Another interesting point that might confirm some editing is what happens to the ball after he catches it. We can see that he catches it with his right hand, places it in his left hand then moves it back to his right hand. After that he tosses it away, but in the moment the ball is supposed to leave his hand, it disappears. It could be that he released the ball outside of camera's field of view, but from his hand movements, I'd expect it to come into the camera's field of view.

Comment: I'm in the "subtle Gilette ad"-camp on this one.

Comment: @AndrejaKo The arc can easily be caused by the spin of the ball, even without wind. There is nothing extraordinary about the trajectory.

Comment: My question is, shouldn't the cameraman have seen it coming?

Comment: the camera guy isn't a trained ball player

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Please explain that. Unless the ball has a very unusual moment of inertia, it wouldn't change the direction like that.

Comment: @Monkey Tuesday Could it be the symptom of cameraman disassociation with reality? There were cases where cameramen were shot and killed while recording the shooter and they didn't take any evasive actions while he shooter was preparing to shoot them.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Read up on the [Magnus effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph To me it looks like it would be insignificant in this case.

Comment: @Andrejako could be, the cameraman was focused on getting the shot or something, I don't know.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Where do you get that from? The Magnus effect is really not insignificant (it can lift wingless airplanes! how insignificant can it be?). Did you ever watch football (soccer)? Bent flanks or goal shots are actually pretty common there, there is even a special word for them – “[curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(football))” – and some of them are [quite famous](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pl0LHM-33Io?t=0m45).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I do watch football and have never seen anything that could be explained by significant influence of Magnus effect.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vAzG-7MUHc this one is more famous imo

Comment: @AndrejaKo What can I say? You are [arguing from personal incredulity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance#Argument_from_incredulity.2FLack_of_imagination). I can’t *make* you believe. But nothing in physics says that the throw in the video is the least bit implausible, you are inventing objections. If you have never seen a curl in football then I suggest that you weren’t watching properly. We have now posted *two* videos in this comment thread which demonstrate a *significant* Magnus effect in aiding to achieve a goal.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph  Well, then don't try to convince me. I never asked for you to make me believe. May I suggest that you instead of trying to convince me, try to make a well researched, well referenced answer to the question? I'm sure that it will be much more productive thing to do than arguing with me.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I can’t confidently answer any of the questions asked by the OP, so I won’t try. What I *can* do (and did) is provide evidence showing that one of the supposed arguments showing this as fake is clearly wrong.

Comment: The ball goes straight, and then suddenly swerves *and speeds up*. Eeeehehe. No. (And now I saw the frame by frame analysis proving what my eyes told me about this already QED).

Comment: @AndrejaKo: The Magnus effect is very real but it causes the trajectory to *curve*. Not have a sudden change of direction. :-)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro I wasn't disputing the Magnus effect itself. I just said that I haven't seen it in football and that I do not believe that it could have caused the trajectory change shown in seventh second of the video. I did play the video very slowly using VLC player and the seventh second looked very unrealistic to me.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: If course you have seen the Magnus effect. When you see a curve ball in football, you see the Magnus effect. The trajectory change in this picture can *not* be ascribed to the Magnus effect. It's not a curve ball, it suddenly changed direction and speed. (Note: http://www.onthecan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/handegg.jpg, but since we are both from  Europe I guess we mean the same.)

Comment: @Lennart: nonsense. There are simply [too few frames](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlIteL1qAWc) to determine this with confidence. The sudden change in speed and direction may well be an artifact of the video encoding – note that the *whole* video stops at this point, not just the ball. This kind of skepticism is uninformed, and very similar to the moon-hoax argument that the “shadow of the flag is all wrong”: superficially plausible, but doesn’t stand up to scrutiny. The few frames of this video simply don’t allow us to judge one way or another.

Comment: @Konrad: No, the whole video does not stop, and no, it can't be an artifact of the encoding either. Sorry. "Too few frames" is a opinion. I saw directly, without going frame by frame, that the trajectory is wrong. The frame by frame just proves it. That is *not* a physically possible trajectory.

Comment: Fake as. 6 second frame the ball is hit straight if you bother to watch.

Comment: @Stavros: While you're right it's fake, baseballs travel like it does in the video all the time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This article does a very good job of piling on the evidence for the video being **fake**:
http://www.politifact.com/florida/statements/2011/may/24/evan-longoria/rays-3b-evan-longorias-spectacular-barehanded-catc/

The evidence is primarily circumstantial, so far no one involved has explicitly admitted it was fake.

> In the video there are four Gillette logos visible -- two behind home plate and two on a roof facade over the third-base bleachers. But those logos aren't part of McKechnie Field in real life, Trevor Gooby, the Pirates' director of Florida operations, told a reporter for Patch.com. The logos were added digitally and included in the final video that was posted on YouTube.

Already we know that *some* aspect of the video was altered. It would be a fallacy of generalization to then say that the catch itself was therefore also altered, but the evidence supports that theory.

The video itself was uploaded by a person who lists their company as Gillette and the recording itself was recorded following a 6 hour recording session for Gillette commercials featuring Evan, suggesting that it too is part of their marketing campaign.

If you're still looking for evidence that this was not meant to be part of an actual newscast,

> there's the reporter and the video graphic identifying Longoria. There is no television station symbols or letters on the video, and the reporter is holding a microphone without a "flag" that identifies the station where the reporter works. Perhaps even stranger, we could not find the video posted on any news site. (Surely, a TV station would love to claim the video as theirs.)

The circumstances of the batting practice also seemed contrived, according to baseball reporter Topkin of the times.

> Topkin noted several things that aren't typical during a batting practice session. There is no cage surrounding the batter to catch foul balls or stop pitches that aren't hit. There's also no screen protecting the batting practice pitcher. There are no coaches in the video hitting ground balls and no other fielders on the baseball diamond to track down any hits.

Furthermore, the batter himself acts oblivious to the entire event. He never yells a warning when the ball heads straight for the interview and crew, and after the catch is made, he resumes a normal batting stance and ignores the congregation in spite of the cheers from the other supposed players on the field.

On the physics side, while the initial hit and resulting trajectory is normal, a [frame by frame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlIteL1qAWc) of the video shows abnormal ball movement right when the catch is made.

> The ball that's caught clearly comes from a different location and angle than the ball hit their direction. You probably saw this in the original video, but this was slowed down to 1FPS to make it more clear. The ball clearly doesn't move for multiple frames, then changes direction, [that's] clear video tampering.

Finally, the words of Gillette spokesperson Norton addressing questions about the video were a cryptic refusal to claim the video was real or admit it was fake, which is very much in the spirit of viral marketing campaigns:

> The video was filmed while on location for a Gillette Fusion ProGlide commercial... We'll leave the 'is it real?' debate up to the viewers.

So as I said, primarily circumstantial evidence along with a fairly solid theory on the frames surrounding the catch being doctored, as the Gillette logos in the park were.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, [snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/photos/advertisements/longoria.asp) has an article on it in which they have quotes from Longoria.  Unfortunately, they don't list a source for the quotes, which is rather unlike them.  It's a fake.